# Google Maps API issue with non-English addresses (PHP/CURL)

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I'm implementing Google Maps service with PHP/CURL and currently have a problem with Maps API.
I am sending queries to Google Maps with English and Russian addresses.
English address works fine, while Russian address fails with 602 (address not found)

Weird thing is that if I copy-paste curl query with Russian address to browser, it works fine (returns 200 and coords).

My code is

```
public static function google_geolocator($geoloc){
    $geoloc = urlencode(implode(" ",$geoloc));
    $query = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q={$geoloc}&sensor=true&oe=utf8";
    echo $query;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);      
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $json = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    return $data;
}
```

I searched through Internets and figured out some hacks with User-Agent and &oe=utf8 and so on, but none of those seem to work. The main thing that confuses me, again, is that this method works perfectly with address in English, but fails with Russian. Although pasting query into browser works perfect in both cases.

Thank you in advance!

**small update**: query like

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4+%D0%9A%D0%BE+%D0%9F%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82&sensor=true&oe=utf8
```

works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox (same 602), while

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Thailand+Koh+Phuket&sensor=true&oe=utf8
```

works fine in both

**upd2**
var_dumping($data) returns

```
{
"name": "Таиланд Ко Пхукет",
"Status": {
    "code": 602,
    "request": "geocode"
    }
}
```

and name field is absolutely the same as in Chrome response.

**upd3** alright, the thing is if i change location name in Russian slightly, both Chrome and FF return 200 and coordinates. The problem seems to be that Chrome is bit more "intellectual" while communicating with Google. Refactored method so location names are always provided in English no matter what current locale is. Looks like it's better not to mess with Google and character sets different from English.

Comment: Where does `$geoloc` come from and what encoding is it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The main thing that confuses me, again, is that this method works perfectly with address in English, but fails with Russian.

You are telling Google to expect UTF-8 data, but you're probably sending it something else. UTF-8 is a double-byte encoding - plain old ASCII characters consist of one byte, just as in ASCII; Russian and other characters of two or more. That's why the English alphabet often works, but as soon as other characters come into play, things break.  Most likely, your Cyrillic characters are getting garbled (= stored as an encoding other than UTF-8) somewhere along the way, before they enter your query.

Make sure the values in `$geoloc` are UTF-8 encoded. If they come from a file, make sure *that* is UTF-8 encoded. If they come from a database, make sure the tables and the database connection are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: $geoloc is an $array($country_name, $location_name). Array values are provided from DB, corresponding tables encoding is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: @paulus then I would check the database connection (and do a test output to see what the characters look like)

Comment: database connection is fine, i have a test unit for this method and can switch between locales instantly. I have figured out difference in output between Firefox and Chrome, updated question accordingly. I wonder what can I do to figure out insides of a query from Chrome and Firefox. Maybe then I'll be able to locate the problem

Comment: @paulus what does an `echo $geoloc;` show you? (make sure to include the information what character set your script has - you can see it in the browser's "encoding" menu)  Ideally before the urlencode()

Comment: english **Thailand+Koh+Phuket** Russian: **%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4+%D0%9A%D0%BE+%D0%9F%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82** Both FF and Chrome have UTF-8

Comment: UTF-8 in both cases, but query response is different in Chrome and FF

Comment: @paulus Are you 100% sure the output encoding of your script is UTF-8 when you do the `var_dump()`?

Comment: @paulus ah, I see. Really strange, but if you can use the workaround, I guess it will do!

Comment: thanks for you help, Pekka. I'll accept your answer seems we have lots of useful info regarding encoding and google